# get Firestore subcollection on Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

My Android app has documents saved in Firestore following the path `val documentName = "pets/$userid/$animal/$animalId"`. *Animal* can be cat, dog, bird, etc. I want to get all the pets owned by a specific user and then I want to iterate through the list of pets. How do I do that? I haven't been able to find an example. So basically I have

```
firestore.document("pets/$userId").get().addOnSuccessListener {
    // now what?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to loop over all collections in the client-side SDKs, and also no way to query across collections with different names.

So the only real option is to perform a separate query for each subcollection:

```
firestore.document("pets/$userId/cat").get()...
firestore.document("pets/$userId/dog").get()...
firestore.document("pets/$userId/bird").get()...
```

And then you'd merge them client-side.

I'd also consider whether you really need these subcollections though. You can also store all of them in a single subcollection, and use a field to differentiate between animal types. That is a simpler model, which probably will work fine for this use-case.

Comment: The thing is I need to use `animalId` as a sort of index for quick updates. And because Firestore requires this `col/doc/col/doc` alternating model, this is the approach I found. What else might you recommend so that I can still perform quick updates on any specific collection? Thanks

Comment: If you put all pets in a single document, you'd just give it a fixed name, e.g. `animals` or something like that.

Comment: What you are saying makes sense and I already considered it. It might seem obvious but the problem is that "pets/$userid/animals" is very much similar to saying "pets/$userid/pets". At least in my use case they are pretty much equivalent, so that I would be adding the redundancy just because of idiosyncrasies of Firestore and it honestly does look weird. It doesn't help my case trying to convince my team to use Firebase and Firestore

Comment: if only I could name the collection "pets/$userid". Then each doc would simply be "pets/$userId/animalId"

Comment: I often find myself introducing meaningless collections in the Firestore model. They're not a problem, just a nuisance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't query across multiple subcollections in a single query.  A query has to target a single collection or subcollection (or a collection group query that targets all collections with the exact same name).  Also Firestore client SDKs can't list subcollections under a document.

You should probably restructure your data to support the queries you intend to make, which means putting the entire list of things in a single subcollection with a predictable name.